# Using headless chrome with url parameters

Tags: shell, ubuntu, google-chrome-headless

I have installed Google Chrome on my Ubuntu 20 VM using apt. When I run a command such as

```
google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf="/var/www/reports/report.pdf" --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw /var/www/html/temp.html
```

Everything works fine, I get a pdf of the rendered html page.
However, if I add some url parameters such as:

```
google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf="/var/www/reports/report.pdf" --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw /var/www/html/temp.html?foo=bar
```

Then the resulting PDF is blank. It contains the header and footer but nothing else.
Firstly, has anyone else come across this or am I doing something wrong? Perhaps this it is built in to headless chrome to not accept url parameters?

I have searched through Google and cannot find an answer to this so any help is gratefully received.

EDIT: just to add; I have tried escaping the question mark using a back slash but this also didn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @KJ but I'm afraid it still doesn't work. I have tried `"/var/www/html/temp.html?foo=bar"` as well as `"http://www/html/temp.html?foo=bar"` but neither worked. I just get a blank document with the header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add back-slash `( \ )` in all query parameters.
I am posting example here, please have a look!

```
initial_html_file_path = /var/www/html/temp.html?foo=bar&foo2=bar2

converted_html_file_path = /var/www/html/temp.html\?foo\=bar\&foo2\=bar2
```

---

**-> Final script**

```
google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf="/var/www/reports/report.pdf" --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw /var/www/html/temp.html\?foo\=bar\&foo2\=bar2
```